# After setting CORS, endpoints of web services are not retrieving data

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-server, windows-server-2016, amazon-cloudfront, iis-10

Well, maybe I am not providing enough information to you all. Hope you can help me, give a clue or hint, or guide me how to advance.

I have an application that is consuming data from a web service. The application is hosted in AWS. The web services are hosted in a virtual Windows Server 2016 with IIS 10.

After adding the following in CORS, the
Application is returning 500 status code when is calling these endpoints from the web server:

```
X-Frame-Options, SAMEORIGIN
Strict-Transport-Security, max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
X-Content-Type-Options, nosniff
X-XSS-Protection, 1; mode=block
Cache-Control, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Content-Security-Policy, default-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' *.domain.com; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src 'self' *.domain.com data:; connect-src 'self' *.domain.com; font-src 'self' *.domain.com data:;
Access-Control-Allow-Origin, *
Access-control-allow-methods, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
Access-control-allow-headers, Content-Type, Authorization
Access-control-allow-credentials, true
```

Do I need to do something extra in the cloudfront? API-gateway? Lambdas? Backend code in Node.js? Additional configuration on IIS?

Please, any help will be really appreciated.

Many Thanks

Comment: Open up `applicationHost.config` or your `web.config` file(s) to explain how you configured CORS. Also use FRT to learn more about the 500 response(s), https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/health-diagnostic-performance/troubleshoot-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis-85

Comment: @LexLi. Thanks for your response. I have configured CORS by web.config, but also, I have configured the CORS in the apppool and site by IIS. What information do you need to provide support to us?

Comment: Nope. I am not providing support to you, but just gave you hints on how to improve this question to a level that someone else might help you out. People do need to see what XML elements you use to configure CORS, as typically you need to use IIS CORS module (the XML elements under `<cors>`), https://blogs.iis.net/iisteam/getting-started-with-the-iis-cors-module

Comment: @LexLi. Hhhmmm.... Really? Because when you gave those 2 pages from Microsoft to me I really thought that you are providing me support. Without you , it would be really hard to text in google my error and click Search.... Many Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, but I cannot explain you all the reason for that or why is working.

As resume, we are using Windows Server 2016 and IIS 10. We have 2 synchronized web servers.

Well, the solution was configured the CORS just in one server (thinking now, maybe the primary one), and blank the other one.

Suddenly, the web services started to work. It was tested by Postman and, directly, from the application that is consuming data from this web services and everything was fine.